# Laravel 5.6 - relation one to many(invert) - doesn't work

Tags: laravel

I'm learning relations.
Where is the mistake in my student - gender relation?

Students table:

```
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('gender_id')
                ->unsigned()
                ->references('id')
                ->on('genders')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Genders table:

```
        Schema::create('genders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

StudentsController

```
use App\Student;
use App\Gender;

class StudentsController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $students = Student::all();
    return view('index', compact('students'));
}
```

Index.blade

```
<pre>{{var_dump($students[0]->gender_id->name)}}</pre>
```

error msg. There are no object in $students.

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Gender model:

```
    public function students() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Student');
}
```

Student model:

```
    public function gender() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Gender');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the relationship using the relationship method/attribute, not the related field. So, you need to use `gender`, not `gender_id`.

```
<pre>{{var_dump($students[0]->gender->name)}}</pre>
```

Be aware that you will get the same error if the student doesn't have a related gender.

Answer (score 0):

why do you create a new table for gender ? every student will have only one gender ( female / male ) so there is no need to save it in another table, just set a column for gender in the students table, if you need all males students you run this one :

male students :

```
$males = Student::where('gender', 'male')->get();
```

female students :

```
$females = Student::where('gender', 'female')->get();
```

Comment: Ok greate! then when you need to access the relation you can use, you access the relation with the function name :
`<pre>{{ var_dump($students[0]->gender->name) }}</pre>`

it's a good practice to load the relation with eager loading to load only one query
`Student::with('gender')->get();`

have a look 
[ eager loading ]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading